# hash in url does not load different page

Tags: html, hyperlink, tabs, zend-framework2, nav

In my nav I have a link to `View Profile`, `Edit Profile` and a link to `My Projects`. The url structure looks like this:

```
/users/username                  <-- View Profile
/users/username/edit             <-- Edit Profile
/users/username/edit#my-projects <-- My Projects
```

My `href` links are those exactly, now if I am on my homepage or any other page besides `/users/` it will open `Edit Profile` and then `My Projects` tab on that page when you click the `My Projects` link in the nav. However, if you have clicked `View Profile` first and then click `My Projects` it will just append the hash `#my-projects` to the end of the current url `/users/username#my-projects` instead of going to `/users/username/edit#my-projects`.

Is there something I am missing when linking to another page and having a hash at the end of the link?

********UPDATE********

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a href="/users/gmaniac" class="w-current">View Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/gmaniac/edit">Edit Profile</a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a href="/users/gmaniac/edit#my-projects">My Projects</a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't think this will help, but I am using `zf2` if that changes how routing works or not.

Unfortunately, I do not have an example outside of local and production.

Comment: Please add your HTML code to your question and If possible post a link to a demo.

Comment: let me know if you need more

Comment: Basically the hash does target now the element with the id "my-projects". It should be possible to do some javascript magic to send you to another page, but thats unnecessary. You might consider changing the structure a little. `/users/username/my-projects` or `/users/username/projects/my-projects` for example. Note: If you want you can try this by adding a element with the id "my-projects" on the page. The browser will automatically jump to this point (unless the window height is already too small)

Comment: thanks @AlexG your comment got me looking at the page it was on. So if on the page there is an `id` of that hash it will only add it to the current url otherwise it will load the new url.